# How to open new tab and enter address into it using webdriver

Tags: java, webdriver

I want to open www.google.com in one tab and then open new tab and open www.facebook.com
I am using Below code but it open facebook in first tab

```
driver.get("www.google.com");    
driver.findElement(By.tagName("Body")).sendKeys(keys.CONTROL + "t");//opens new tab  
driver.get("www.facebook.com");//but load facebook in first tab i.e on google page
```

Is this because I am using same name driver.get??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use java awt Robot class as below.

```
          driver.get("http://www.google.com");    
          Robot r = new Robot();        
          r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
          r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
          r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
          r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
          driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

If the code to open the new tab worked, you can use `driver.switchTo().window()` to switch to the newly opened tab (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18150682/378897)).

But If the tab didn't open, Selenium does not provide any mechanism to do this, so you have to implement around it (like using the `java.awt.Robot` class)

You should also consider just using two different instances of the WebDriver and run both your sites in its own window

Comment: Thnks..but what i need to pass to window()