# Multithreading in python selenium

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium-webdriver

I want to open and login 5 tabs concurrently without delay in between in tabs. I have tried:

```
import threading
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def openurl(threadId):
    print(threading.currentThread().getName(),' Thread')
    url = ('https://www.facebook.com/')
    print(url)
    driver.execute_script("window.open('{0}')".format(url))
    #driver.title(threadId)
    time.sleep(0.1)

    driver.set_window_size(920, 680)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "email").send_keys("xx")
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "pass").send_keys("yy")
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "loginbutton").click()


if __name__=='__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    windows_before  = driver.current_window_handle
    for i in range(5):
        t1 = threading.Thread(name=i,target=openurl, args=(i,))
        t1.start()
        t1.join()
```

but it is throwing:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\1024983\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py",
>   line 870, in run
>       self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "C:\Users\1024983\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\fb-thread.py",
>   line 30, in openurl
>       driver.find_element(By.ID, "email").send_keys("xx")   File
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
>   selector","selector":"[id="email"]"}   (Session info:
>   chrome=78.0.3904.108)

If I increased sleep time, there is a delay in-between tabs. I tried to navigate using **driver.title** but my case title is same for all tabs.

Comment: You can use wait for object to appear to be sure on the object appearance in a given time limit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20903328/12422518

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150593/selenium-multiple-tabs-at-once/18150682) might be helpful

Comment: can you help me to create "instances of webdriver" @Shijith

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: this code `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` creates instance of webdriver

Comment: now i edited my error @furas   and  driver = webdriver.Chrome() this creates different browse..but i want to create different tab

Comment: I think its explained on the accepted answer of the link `If you are wanting to have multiple threads all act on the same driver instance, but different tabs, that is NOT possible.`

Comment: Using this also driver = webdriver.Chrome() i am getting same error..taking time to load url if i give time.sleep(2)..again it is sequential only, not parallel multi threading @Shijith..Is there any other way ?

Comment: threads in Python doesn't run at the same time because of `GIL` - you could in main thread first open many browsers, load pages and fill login forms and after filling all forms click all buttons. It would have smaller delay when you click all buttons almost at the same time.

Comment: `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` creates instance of webdriver (as you asked) and every instance means separted browse but maybe it will better to control separated browser. But if you use tabs or separated browser problem is always the same - to synchronize threads (or processes) so they will click button at the same moment.

Comment: clicking the button at same moment..atleast this is what i need..i created driver = webdriver.Chrome() inside loop and sent as a parameter still getting error..can you please modify my code for **clicking the button at same moment in all browser instance**  please..

Comment: Any body please help me to modify my code for **clicking the button at same moment in all browser instance** please..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is example uses threads to run separated browsers which fill form and set `True` in list `buttons` to inform that `login` button is ready to click. When all browsers set `True` in list `buttons` then all of them click buttons.

It seems that it runs amost a the same time - maybe only system has some to makes so many connections at the same time.

I used list `buttons` to synchronize all threads. Every thread get number to have own place in list. I don't use `append(True)` because I'm not sure it can be thread-safe.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from threading import Thread

def func(number):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    #driver.set_window_size(920, 680)
    driver.get(url)

    driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("xx")
    driver.find_element_by_id("pass").send_keys("yy")
    b = driver.find_element_by_id("loginbutton")

    buttons[number] = True
    print(buttons)

    # wait for other buttons
    while not all(buttons):
        pass

    print('click', number)
    b.click()

# ---

url = 'https://www.facebook.com/'

number_of_threads = 5

#buttons = [False * number_of_threads] # create place 
buttons = []

threads = []

for number in range(number_of_threads):
    t = Thread(target=func, args=(number,)) # get number for place in list `buttons`
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
    buttons.append(False) # create place 

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

---

**EDIT:** The same with `threading.Barrier(5)` and 5 threads will have to run `barrier.wait()` to move forward.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from threading import Thread, Barrier

def func(barrier):

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    #driver.set_window_size(920, 680)
    driver.get(url)

    driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("xx")
    driver.find_element_by_id("pass").send_keys("yy")
    b = driver.find_element_by_id("loginbutton")

    print('wait for others')
    barrier.wait()

    print('click')
    b.click()

# ---

url = 'https://www.facebook.com/'

number_of_threads = 5

barrier = Barrier(number_of_threads)

threads = []

for _ in range(number_of_threads):
    t = Thread(target=func, args=(barrier,)) 
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Comment: Thank you so much..I enhanced this same program if i load the dynamic url which is in excel,it is taking last url only.. My code : number_of_threads = sheet.nrows url=sheet.cell_value(i, 0)..

Comment: I don't know what you try to do but maybe you should send url as parameter to thread.