# How can I open a new tab with selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to make a program that opens multiple websites, but I can't get it to press `control-t`. I've tried multiple solutions, but I can't find one that works. When I do the keydown method, I get an error that says

```
webdriver has no attribute key_down
```

and when I try `send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')` it doesn't raise any errors, or do anything. How can I open a new tab?

Here's my try :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://youtube.com")
search = driver.find_element_by_id("search")
#search.keydown(Keys.CONTROL)

#Webelement.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('t').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()

search.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+'t')
time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it as

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
search = driver.find_element_by_id("search")

driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.google.com')")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you can try :

```
from selenium import webdriver

webBrowser = webdriver.<>()
  
# This is first tab
webBrowser.get('<>')

# Second tab
webBrowser.execute_script("window.open('about:blank','secondtab');")
webBrowser.switch_to.window("secondtab")
webBrowser.get('<>')

# Third tab
webBrowser.execute_script("window.open('about:blank','thirdtab');")
webBrowser.switch_to.window("thirdtab")
webBrowser.get('<>')
```

You can learn more about it from [Python – Opening multiple tabs using Selenium](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opening-multiple-tabs-using-selenium)

Additionally I think you also have you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18150682/12446721).

> However, if you want to run something on multiple windows, then I recommend having multiple instances of webdriver. It is much easier to manage, and is supported (There are workarounds on opening a new tab/window, such as pressing a hotkey that opens a new window, but they aren't supported).

Answer (score 2):

```py
driver.switch_to.new_window()
```

[From the webdriver docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.switch_to.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.switch_to.SwitchTo.new_window)

You can pass in `'tab'` or `'window'`. For `ChromeDriver`, it opens a tab by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pyautogui` to doy to open new tab using `ctrl+t` :

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
pyautogui.press('t')
pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')
```